# Run function when pressing button and insert into form

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

So I have this form, where I want to add a button which makes a function run.

This is how my form looks like:

```
<form  action="" method="POST"> 
CVR-nummer:<br> 
<input name="cvr" id="cvr" type="text" value="" size="30"/> <button onclick="<?php getinfo(); ?>">Run the function</button><br> 
Navn:<br> 
<input name="navn" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($navn)) {echo $navn;} ?>" size="30"/><br>
Adresse:<br> 
<input name="adresse" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($adresse)) {echo $adresse;} ?>" size="30"/><br>
Postnummer:<br> 
<input name="postnr" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($postnr)) {echo $postnr;} ?>" size="30"/><br>
By:<br> 
<input name="by" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($by)) {echo $by;} ?>" size="30"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Registrer"/> 
</form>
```

And this is my function which uses an API

```
<?php 
function getinfo() {
    $cvr = "12345678";
    $api = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://cvrapi.dk/{$cvr}/"),true);
    $navn = $api['navn'];
    $adresse = $api['adresse'];
    $postnr = $api['postnr'];
    $by = $api['by'];
}

?>
```

When I click the button I want it to:
1. Get value of the cvr-field.
2. Validate cvr-field so it has exactly 8 numbers.
3. If validation OK it must set the variables.
4. The variables must be shown in the form.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

**UPDATE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkCVR()
{
    var cvr = document.getElementById("cvr").value;
    var reg = new RegExp("^[0-9]{8}$");
    if(!reg.test(cvr))
    {
        document.getElementById("cvr_error").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("cvr_error").innerHTML = "CVR Error!";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("cvr_error").style.display = 'none';
        // var url = "http://cvrapi.dk/"+cvr+"/";
        // var url = "http://haxify.org/result.php";
        var url = "json.txt";

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                document.getElementById("navn").value = json["navn"];
                document.getElementById("adresse").value = json["adresse"];
                document.getElementById("postnr").value = json["postnr"];
                document.getElementById("by").value = json["by"];
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
}
</script>
<form  action="" method="POST"> 
    CVR-nummer:<br> 
    <input name="cvr" id="cvr" type="text" value="" size="30"/>
    <input type="button" onClick="checkCVR()" value="Run the function" /><br />
    <span id="cvr_error" style="color:red;display:none;"></span>
    Navn:<br />
    <input name="navn" id="navn" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br />
    Adresse:<br />
    <input name="adresse" id="adresse" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br />
    Postnummer:<br />
    <input name="postnr" id="postnr" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br />
    By:<br />
    <input name="by" id="by" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Registrer"/> 
</form>
```

This one actually works on one website but does not work on my own site. Is there any requirements for any software or something, or what can be the reaseon for this to not work on my specific website?

Test:
http://haxify.org/form_v4.php

Comment: Unfortunately it's not quite that easy. Keep in mind, that PHP gets executed on the server and your HTML page is on the clients computer. The browser never gets the php code and thus cannot run it. Your `getinfo()` doesn't actually echo or print anything. Therefore the browser will receive `<button onclick="">` (just one of the examples, why this wouldn't work). I suggest, that you start off with a html form based tutorial like [this](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Creating-Form-Insert-Data-P280.html) one.

Comment: As @TimBodeit said, the difference between client-side and server-side makes what you're doing a difficoult task. You should try with a mix of javascript and php sending of variables to an indermediary script.

Comment: I have got it translated to pure javascript, so maybe now I am closer to the goal? What do you say?

Comment: If I use this URL, I can get the content:
http://haxify.org/result.php

If I use this URL, i can NOT:
https://cvrapi.dk/35021566

But it should have the same content :-S